# What I can convert TimeStamp into?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column of type `timestamp` which updates every time record updated.

We have some specific logic for syncronizing data and I'd like to store timestamp's value in other table so I can compare to source later. Can't make new column of type `timestamp` as it's auto-updated.

Which SQL type should I use in TableB for maximum performance and quicker CASTs on comparisons?

Comment: You are syncing data across two tables? The auto-updated part would likely be a `TRIGGER`.

Comment: If you must convert, I'd go with BIGINT

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. There are likely some better ways to keep your data in synch than whatever it is you are currently doing.

Comment: @SeanLange every existing software full of xy problems. Can't rewrite whole thing every time we need to improve it, right? Questions was pretty simple, we need to store timestamps in other place to later compare with source, data kept in sync but completely in different forms/etc

Comment: What do you need to know that is not covered by [Data type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) and [`rowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)? Where do you see performance bottlenecks? (See [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Bonus: [premature optimization](http://xkcd.com/1691/).)

Comment: If you think that all software is full of xy problems then I would make the case that you don't understand what an xy problem actually is.

Comment: I would use `binary(8)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> timestamp is the synonym for the rowversion data type and is subject
>   to the behavior of data type synonyms. In DDL statements, use
>   rowversion instead of timestamp wherever possible. For more
>   information, see Data Type Synonyms (Transact-SQL).

and

> The timestamp syntax is deprecated.

and

> Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary
>   numbers within a database. rowversion is generally used as a mechanism
>   for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes.

So putting this together: Think of `TIMESTAMP` (which should be `ROWVERSION`) as a meaningless 8-byte binary. If you really want to do something with it, you can store it as 8-byte binary or you can convert it to a type with a length of 8 bytes. In this case I'd suggest `BIGINT`.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately we are on SQL2008 and SSMS doesn't have `rowversion` choice available. Will stick to `timestamp` for now. Especially that all DB designed with it everywhere. Will be using BigInt.

Answer (score 0):

First, understand that timestamp is NOT a value of type date and time, but rather a unique identifier based on this type of data.

I suggest you review the documentation [Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#DateandTimeFunctions) and choose the type of data that best suits your needs. This could be ***DATETIME2, DATETIMEOFFSET, DATETIME***